# Protocol Buffer Error on compile during GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_MIN_PROTOC_VERSION check

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, protoc

I'm currently getting an error which points me to these lines in the header file produced by protoc:

```
#if 2006001 < GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_MIN_PROTOC_VERSION
#error This file was generated by an older version of protoc which is
#error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please
#error regenerate this file with a newer version of protoc.
#endif
```

But my protoc version matches the one above:

```
protoc --version
libprotoc 2.6.1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Originally my protoc version was 3.0.0 then reinstalled it by syncing back to 2.6.1 and doing the steps; make distclean, ./configure , make, make install to install the desired 2.6.1 version. I needed the older version since that's the one installed in our servers.

Comment: Are you sure your previously (with 3.0.0 version) generated protobuf headers were removed/updated?

Comment: Yup, I deleted those 3.0.0 headers explicitly. I also checked the file and the check validation for the version is as written above with the 2006001 version comparison

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is that the installed headers on your system (in /usr/include/google/protobuf or /usr/local/include/google/protobuf) are from a newer version of Protocol Buffers than your `protoc`. It may be the case that you have both versions installed in different locations, and the wrong one is being used.

> But my protoc version matches the one above:

Yes, because that code was generated by your `protoc`, and it knows its own version. The code is asking: "Is my version (2006001) less than the minimum version which the installed headers claim is required (GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_MIN_PROTOC_VERSION)?"

Comment: Is there a way to check which version of the headers were installed in my system? I tried looking at the files themselves and can't find any hints on what version it is.

Comment: @the_qbf: Yes, look at `google/protobuf/stubs/common.h` and look for the `GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERSION` macro around 100 lines in.

Comment: Competent and helpful answer, helped me to figure out what was my problem. Thank you, sir!

Comment: Hi, any way to specify to  a program which version of `protoc` to be used? I also have two versions of protoc, and would want to specify to `caffe` which one to use.

Comment: @AruniRC it would be up to the program's build system to provide you with a way to specify. There is no general way, other than having only one installed at a time.

Comment: @KentonVarda thanks! I figured out a way by specifying the protobuf I want first in the PATH variable, without having to remove the other version of protobuf (other things depended on that old version).

Comment: or if you did like me: you might have updated the cc file but forgotten to update the header file