# Protobuf version conflict when using caffe (C++) on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu-16.04, caffe

I use Ubuntu 16.04, gcc 5.4.0 and CLion (C++ environment).
I am trying to use caffe. And it needs protobuf for installation.
So, it works fine in Python, but C++ gives me a run-time exception:

```
libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:78] This program was compiled against version 2.6.1 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, which is not compatible with the installed version (3.3.0). Contact the program author for an update. If you compiled the program yourself,  makesure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library. (Version verification failed in "/build/mir-ui6vjS/mir-0.26.3+16.04.20170605/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src/protobuf/mir_protobuf.pb.cc".)
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
    what(): This program was compiled against version 2.6.1 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, which is not compatible with the installed version (3.3.0). Contact the program author for an update. If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library. (Version verification failed in "/build/mir-ui6vjS/mir-0.26.3+16.04.20170605/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src/protobuf/mir_protobuf.pb.cc".)
```

As far as I understood, exception tells me that it needs protobuf 2.6.1, but 3.3.0 is installed.
But command `apt-get upgrade libprotobuf-dev` gives me `libprotobuf-dev is already the newest version (2.6.1-1.3)`. so i do have 2.6.1.

Could you, please, advice me how could i fix it ?

P.S. I dont know if it is important or not but I added caffe path to ~/.bashrc

Comment: how many version of protobuf you are using?i guess you might have installed them separtely,you need to uninstall libprotobuf-dev and build caffe again..

Comment: Here is what I did.

1)sudo apt-get remove libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler

2)sudo apt-get upgrade libprotobuf-dev
(to make sure that it is removed, it is)

3)In caffe folder: **make clean**   and **make all**

In the end CLion gives the same reesult.

Comment: what do you get with this  protoc --version

Comment: WOW, it really gives me 3.3.0. 
  I will try to remove thisone and rebuild caffe one more time.

Comment: i think that one would be more compatible with caffe,can you try to  reinstall gcc

Comment: Ok, seems like now I have   another sub-problem.
I reinstalled protobuf by  doing 
sudo apt-get remove —auto-remove libprotoc-dev
sudo apt-get remove —auto-remove protobuf-compiler
sudo rm `which protoc`
(Actually i got this computer in current condition, so I don't know where protobuf was installed )
Now when I am trying to "make all" caffe I get:  #error This file was generated by an older version of protoc...

Comment: according to this quastion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744529/protocol-buffer-error-on-compile-during-google-protobuf-min-protoc-version-check
I need to rpelace ald files via 2.6.1. version, Could Ypu advice how ?

Comment: You need to get protobuf from github and build it as you are building caffe,make all,make install

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the version that you want to use in

> CAFFE_ROOT/cmake/Protobuf.cmake

by adding the version number in find_package :

```
find_package( Protobuf 2.6.1 REQUIRED )
```

That way you can keep the multiple versions it doesn't matter.

Ps : I'm not sure version 3.3.0 is supported anyway look at [this](https://github.com/dividiti/ck-caffe/issues/111).